# refreshing a page in jquery mobile after a pageshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Am trying to refresh a page on pageshow in jquery mobile

Tried code:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#schoolperformance", function(){ 
showLoadMsg : false,
reloadPage : true,
});
```

But i keep on getting an error of unexpected token which points to the part{ reload page:true} when viewing in the console

Comment: You have 2 mistakes in your code. A) You have a comma too much. (The one at the end of line 4.) B) The third parameter is a function, not an array. This code thus also trigger errors after "*fixing*" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the use of pagecontainers (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change).

For instance:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( 
    "change", 
    "#schoolperformance", 
    { reload : true, showLoadMsg : false } 
);
```

Comment: fyi; `reload/reloadPage: true` works only with URLs.

Comment: What about passing a function on the change page  example:  $.ajax(..) that is after changing the page

Comment: That is doable. This thread provides great information about page events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events